# run node-red with selenium driver

Tags: node.js, selenium, mocha.js, node-red

I will run mocha test suite's to test a node-red node.
Therefore i use mocha and the selenium driver.

I had a Problem to run the node-red module.
If i start the test with `$ mocha --ui **tdd**` the node-red application cant't find my flow. Because he is searching in folder '~/.node-red/**tdd**'. I don't known why the mocha **[option]** is set as path?
Only with command `$ mocha` the function `suite();` is not define?

I would solve the problem to init node-red with my own settings.
Like this way..
http://nodered.org/docs/embedding.html

With this way i can run node-red after 'RED.start()' but i get no URL and can't open node-red in the selenium driver?

```
require('colors');
var async = require ('async');
var fs = require('fs');

var node = require ('../../mynode.js');
var assert = require('node-assertthat');

var http = require('http');
var http = require('http');
var express = require("express");
var RED = require("node-red");

// Create an Express app
var app = express();

// Add a simple route for static content served from 'public'
app.use("/",express.static("public"));

// Create a server
var server = http.createServer(app);


var settings = {
    settingsFile:"/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/settings.js",
    userDir:"/home/<user>/.nodered",
    flowFile: "flow_<name>.json",
    functionGlobalContext: { }    // enables global context
};

// Initialise the runtime with a server and settings
RED.init(server,settings);


var webdriver = require('../'),
            By = webdriver.By,
            until = webdriver.until;

/* connect to selenium browser */
driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        .forBrowser('chrome')
       .build();


suite('node', function(){
        var driver;
    suite('test setup', function(){
    suite('connect to http://127.0.0.1:1880', function(){       

        setup(function(){
        });    
        test('run Node-Red ',function(done){
            setTimeout(function(){
                /* run node-red */
                RED.start();
                done();
            },2000);    
        });

        test('open URL \'http://localhost:1880/#\'', function(done) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                driver.get('http://localhost:1880/#');
                /* open node-red URL */     
                driver.getTitle().then(function(title) {
            console.log('\nPage title is:\ '+ title.red.bold +"\n");
            assert.that(title, is.equalTo('Node-RED'));
            done();
                });
            },2000);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have set the default route

```
app.use("/",express.static("public"));
```

This is going to clash with Node-RED unless you set the Node-RED routes to something different.

You need to set the httpNodeRoot and the httpAdminRoot in your settings e.g.

```
var settings = {
    settingsFile:"/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/settings.js",
    userDir:"/home/<user>/.nodered",
    flowFile: "flow_<name>.json", 
    httpAdminRoot:"/red",
    httpNodeRoot: "/api",
    functionGlobalContext: { }    // enables global context
};
```

If you do this then you would access Node-RED on localhost as follows:

http://localhost:1880/red

EDIT:
You only need to set the httpNodeRoot if you are using the httpIn node

Comment: this has no effect. 
'
25 Sep 18:40:51 - [info] Flows file : /home/julien/.nodered/flow_<name>.json
25 Sep 18:40:51 - [info] Creating new flow file
25 Sep 18:40:51 - [info] Starting flows
25 Sep 18:40:51 - [info] Started flows
'
I missing the line in the node-red log?
'
25 Sep 18:41:56 - [info] Server now running at http://127.0.0.1:1880/
'

Comment: your code works.
But if i run it with '$ mocha' cannot reach the url '127.0.0.1:1880/red'.
Have you any ideas to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

solved

The Problem was the 'var driver'
In the first 'suite()' i initialized a new 'var drive;' and overwrites the first one. Thats a silly fault.

```
...
 suite('node', function(){
--        var driver;
++        //var drive;
...
```